# FetchError: request to https://discordapp.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, discord.js, node-fetch

I'm working with a Discord bot using the node.js module [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/).

Recently an error appears on start up (when the bot attempts to login) when using the work wifi which I believe was configured in some way that caused it to break.

```
(node:104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://discordapp.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:106:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:104) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The error is thrown from the file `RequestHandler.js` which uses the APIRequest 
method [`make`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/rest/RequestHandler.js#L101) from the file `APIRequest.js` which returns the result from the function [`fetch`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/rest/APIRequest.js#L49) from the file `index.js` which returns a [rejected promise](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/src/index.js#L97).

The variable [`req`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/src/index.js#L74) is the [`ClientRequest`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2f45ad8060e13d5ac912335096d21526f2f9602b/lib/https.js#L36) (from the module [`_http_client`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js)) [returned](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2f45ad8060e13d5ac912335096d21526f2f9602b/lib/https.js#L305) from the method [`request`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) from the https module.

If I comment out the `req.on('error', function (err) { ... });` then I get the following error:

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Which I believe to be thrown from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/stream_base_commons.js#L183) but it's an internal module of Node.js (`internal/stream_base_commons.js`) which I can't edit and continue tracking deeper. Would have to edit and recompile which is not something I know how to do.

When I go to https://discordapp.com/api/v7/gateway/bot I get the response:

```
{"code": 0, "message": "401: Unauthorized"}
```

I need help understanding the exact cause of the original error and if there's any workaround to continue running the bot.

Comment: Does it work outside of the office network?

Comment: @silicakes Yes. It's something to do with either the proxy or something alike.

Comment: So without knowing about your networks settings, one can only speculate about the reason. You should inquire about your companies FW and network policies in order to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just checked the bot login token and it was outdated. Try generating a new bot token on the Discord developer portal !